How to display TabView with images in main window of SwiftUI app on macOS?
I have a following macOS app in SwiftUI:
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        Settings {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            FirstTabView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("First", systemImage: "house")
                }
            SecondTabView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Second", systemImage: "house")
                }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 400, minHeight: 300)
    }
}

struct FirstTabView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("First Tab")
    }
}

struct SecondTabView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Second Tab")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

When I launch this it looks like this (with the main window on the left side, and settings window on the right side):

What I'm trying to get is to make the main window have a TabView displayed in a similar way as it is displayed in the settings window on the right side (which actually I do not need at all, I just put it here to show the difference) that is with icons and labels, but I can't find any way to set it like that. Is it possible to do this for the main app window in swiftui on macos?

I believe that requires that it is a settings window and not the main window
